# Trying to Post a Model back to the Controller, but it creates a new model instead

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tpa class is my base model.

```
public class Tpa
{
    public bool selected { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Data class creates a list of Tpa objects.

```
public class Data
{
    public List<Tpa> Tpas { set; get; }

    public Data()
    {

        this.Tpas = new List<Tpa>();

        this.Tpas.Add(new Tpa()
        {
            selected = false ,
            Id = 1,

        });

        this.Tpas.Add(new Tpa()
        {
            selected = false,
            Id = 2,


        });

        this.Tpas.Add(new Tpa()
        {
            selected = true,
            Id = 3,


        });
    }
}
```

This is my Get.

```
 [HttpGet]
    public virtual ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new Data();
        return View(model);
    }
```

This is my view.

```
@model TpaUpload_2.Models.Data
@using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.TpaUpload_2.Home.ReceiveID(), FormMethod.Post))

<table class="table">
<tr>
@for (int count = 0; count < Model.Tpas.Count; count++)
        {
            var item = Model.Tpas[count];
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox"
                           name=@Html.Raw("'s" + count + "CheckBox'")
                           id=@Html.Raw("'s" + count + "CheckBox'")
                           @*checked="@(item.selected == true)"*@ />
                    <label for=@Html.Raw("'s" + count + "CheckBox'" )></label>
                    <input type='hidden'
                            id=@Html.Raw("'s" + count + "CheckBox'" )
                            name='item.selected'
                            value=@Html.Raw("'"+item.selected+"'")/>
</tr>

</table>
<input  type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

This my Post.

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult ReceiveID(Data myData)
{
...
}
```

I'm trying to use the checkbox value to change the "selected" on the model, and post back the model.
The problem is after the Form is submitted to the Post, the program will construct a new Data object, instead of using the Data model passed to the controller.
What did I do wrong? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are recreating evething at the Data constructor

Comment: That's right, how can I fix that?

Comment: Should I delete the constructor and do it in Get method?

Comment: Yes! The method that renders the view, should provide data for the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructing html with `name` attributes that have absolutely no relationship to you model. When you submit, the `DefaultModelBinder` first initializes your `Data` model (which means that 3 new `Tpa` objects are added to its `Tpas` property. It then tries to find name/value pairs in the form collection that match you model properties but there are none.

First you need to modify you constructor to include only the initialization of the list, and remove the adding of the new items

```
public class Data
{
   public List<Tpa> Tpas { set; get; }
   public Data()
   {
       Tpas = new List<Tpa>();
   }
}
```

And add the items in the GET method

```
public virtual ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new Data();
    model.Tpas .Add(new Tpa(){ selected = false, Id = 1 });
    // add other items
    return View(model);
}
```

Then you need to construct you view correctly using the strongly typed html helpers so that your form controls are correctly named in relationship to your model

```
<table class="table">
  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Tpas.Count; i++)
  {
    <tr>
      <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Tpas[i].Id)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Tpas[i].selected)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Tpas[i].selected)
      </td>
    </tr>
  }
</table>
```

This give your controls the correct name attribute for model binding, for example

```
<input type="hidden" name="Tpas[0].Id" ... />
<input type="hidden" name="Tpas[1].Id" ... />
<input type="hidden" name="Tpas[2].Id" ... />
```

I suggest you compare that with what your currently generating to understand the difference.

Note also your current html is invalid - you have multiple `<tr>` elements inside a `<tr>` elements and you need to include the hidden input for the `Id` property or else this will not post back and you will end up with 3 `Tpa` objects all with `id = 0`.

Comment: Note, answer updated - `m => m.[i].Id` should be `m => m.Tpas[i].Id`

Comment: After the model is passed back to the Post method, "selected"  and "Id" are passed back , but other fields are not. Is there a way to pass the whole model back? Thanks!

Comment: Do I have to make everything input ?

Comment: I did a "    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Tpas[count].field)"  "for every data-field and seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: Yes you need to include a control for each property if you want it to be bound when you submit, but including a whole lot of hidden inputs and posting them back unchanged can degrade performance. Its often better to just include what you need and in the POST method, get the original collection again from the database (or from session)